# Should a concrete curb at a patio door be built on top of or inset into the slab?

Tags: concrete, walls, doors

This is going to be hard to explain, so please bear with me.  I am shrinking down an old 8' sliding glass door Rough opening from what appears to have been an old garage door originally.  The header seems sound, so I plan on framing in under it, about 24"x 80" between the foundation edge which was also the old rough opening edge, and the edge of a the rough opening I want. As this is  for an exterior door I need a minimum clearance of 6" vertical before the bottom of new siding, to prevent water and other issues.  I plan on building a mold to pre-cast a piece of concrete I have designed that will have embedded threads for the sill plate and holes for rebar to be epoxy fixed once in place and connected to existing structures.

My question is this, should I design this to sit on existing slab and set in place with hydraulic cement (my current plan) or should I cut out a chunk of slab and design this to fit down next to the slab?

Remember, this will not be load bearing as it is under the header for the old door.  As such do I need to worry about 'punch through' with the new block as it will not be over a footer as far as I know.

Thanks for reading and thinking about this.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How we normally pour concrete whether it be on top of or next to an existing slab is to anchor it with rebar. Simply drill a hole every 3ft(min) using a bit 1/8in bigger than the rebar and either epoxy the whole and hammer the rebar into place or omit the epoxy if you wish.

Just make sure to keep at least 2in of clearance above the rebar to the top of the concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Keil, if I understand your situation correctly it sounds like you're on the right path. I would set the precast on the existing concrete, but you'll want to seal all around with a silicone-based calk. I don't think you need to worry about any punch through, because it isn't load bearing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in an earthquake zone, I think you'll be fine. Otherwise, I would go with a more secure method of anchoring the new concrete to the old so that it won't scoot away in an earthquake, which could warp the glass and create an evacuation hazard.